# Guest author - URL, base and custom taxonomy - working but unstable

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug, multi-author

I've had help here in the forum to create a custom guest-author taxonomy, custom guest-author url base and to redirect the main author's url (logged WP user) to the guest-author's url.

It is all working but very unstable. Sometimes I get a 404 error in the guest-author's url, as if it couldn't fetch the guest-author's information. I think there might be a conflict in the order of the functions.

I will post the codes I am using in the order they appear in my functions.php:

1. A filter to change the author to guest-author and implode the WP author

```
add_filter( 'the_author', 'guest_author_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_author_display_name', 'guest_author_name' );
 
function guest_author_name( $name ) {
    global $post;
 
    $author = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'autoria', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
 $author = implode( ', ', $author );
    if ( $author )
    $name = $author;
    return $name;
}
```

2. A function to change the author's base URL instead of /author to /autoria

```
 add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');  
 function change_author_permalinks()  
 {  
      global $wp_rewrite;  
      $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'autoria'; 
      $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base. '/%author%';  
 }
```

3. A function to change the author's url to match the new guest-author's urls

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'change_author_to_term' );

function change_author_to_term( $link ) {
    global $post;
    $guest = get_the_terms($post->ID,'autoria');
    if( !$guest )
        return $link;
    return get_term_link($guest[0]->term_id);
}
```

4. Finally, to register the taxonomies, I am using the Custom Post Type UI, which generates the following code:

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_autoria() {

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Autoria.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => esc_html__( "Autoria", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "singular_name" => esc_html__( "Autoria", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "menu_name" => esc_html__( "Autoria", "hello-elementor-child" ),
    ];

    
    $args = [
        "label" => esc_html__( "Autoria", "hello-elementor-child" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'autoria', 'with_front' => true, ],
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "show_tagcloud" => false,
        "rest_base" => "autoria",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "rest_namespace" => "wp/v2",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
        "sort" => false,
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( "autoria", [ "post" ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_autoria' );
```

The only way I could make this work is to delete all the functions, deactivate the Custom Post Type UI plugin, activate the Custom Post Type UI plugin, and then add again the functions.

Is there a way to make this more stable?

Thanks so much

Comment: Remove no.2, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a proper order for these script to run? I suspect this might be causing the instability

Comment: The functions will only run whenever the actions or filters they are hooked onto run. Test, see what effect disabling either of the filters has with regards to instability.